# Using the `print()` and the `repr() ` functions in python alters the number of decimal digits

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding, repr

I try to specify the number of useful digits in case of a numpy array of floats by using the `numpy.round()` function. After, I specify e.g. to use 16 digits and evaluate the `print()` or the `repr()` function on a specific array item I end up with a float of 17 decimal digits.

I tried to understand the problem by creating an array with floats which have 16 decimal digits and play with the `print()`, the `repr()` and the `numpy.round()` functions and the combination of those, as shown in the codes below.

```
#!/bin/python

#Importing
import numpy as np

EIn  = np.array([-0.3136743708333332, -0.3087733416145832, -0.3038723123958332])
print(EIn)
print(EIn[0])
print(repr(EIn[0]))
print(np.round(EIn[0],16))
print(repr(np.round(EIn[0],16)))

EIn = np.round(np.array([-0.3136743708333332, -0.3087733416145832, -0.3038723123958332]),16)
print(EIn)
print(EIn[0])
print(repr(EIn[0]))
print(np.round(EIn[0],16))
print(repr(np.round(EIn[0],16)))
```

The above script produced the output:

```
[-0.31367437 -0.30877334 -0.30387231]
-0.313674370833
-0.31367437083333322
-0.313674370833
-0.31367437083333322
[-0.31367437 -0.30877334 -0.30387231]
-0.313674370833
-0.31367437083333322
-0.313674370833
-0.31367437083333322
```

I would like to understand why the `repr()` and the `print()` functions producing outputs with 17 decimal digits.

Comment: have you read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html? floats don't work with decimal digits, hence you're seeing the base-10 representation closest to the value it's been rounded to.  also note that the `round` in `numpy` isn't as accurate as the builtin version...

Comment: @SamMason I am fine with the concept in the docs, but can not understand why a float rounded to 16 digits is returned with 17 digits. Could you be more specific and point out how this could happen?

Comment: I've just tried running your code and I actually get 16 digit numbers displayed the whole time.  what OS, Python, and numpy versions are you using?

Comment: @SamMason I use Python 2.7.5, numpy 1.7.0-intel under SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64).

Comment: that is so far out of date it's scary, I'd **strongly** encourage you to use a newer version of at least Python!  the oldest version I have here is 2.7.16, and Python 2.7 dying soon https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @GergelyMathe: Re-read the docs. You don't _have_ a "float rounded to 16 digits"; there's not really any such thing. You've used a 16-digits-after-the-point numeric literal written in base 10 to specify the float, but the actual number you get is not exactly equal to that value. Your first value, expressed in the source as `-0.3136743708333332` is actually stored in the internal IEEE 754 binary64 format (that your machine is almost certainly using) as `-0.313674370833333215902172241840162314474582672119140625`.

Comment: ... and now if you ask for the value that's stored as `-0.313674370833333215902172241840162314474582672119140625` to be displayed, what do you expect Python or NumPy to reasonably do? It's not reasonable to show *all* those digits - most are going to be not useful for the user (and smaller values can require *hundreds* of digits to show exactly), so both Python and NumPy quite sensibly choose to round when displaying. The details of exactly how much they round and what mechanism they use for the rounding differ from version to version (as well as between Python and NumPy).

Comment: @SamMason I totally agree with you, but I am not able to upgrade. I use a high performance computing cluster for which I do not have any admin privileges.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you for your detailed answer! Is there a place where these details of rounding from version to version can be checked?

Comment: Hmm, not easily that I know of. To be clear, the details of how `round` works have *not* changed significantly. It's the details of how a float happens to get printed or implicitly converted to string that have changed. And if that matters to you, you should be using explicit string formatting rather than leaving it to `repr` or `str` to choose how to format for you.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right. However, I tried to use these functions as I would achieve to round not to a fix number of decimals, but specify the maximum number of used decimals. I have file names with floats which have different number of decimals. I don't know the number of decimals prior I try to read in those files.

Comment: You can specify the number of decimals when turning your floats to strings; would that help? `'{:.16f}'.format(-0.313674370833333215902172241840162314474582672119140625)` and friends will contain 16 digits, then again you'll get trailing zeros for finite decimals this way. Is it even safe to use these floats as identifiers? If you do arithmetic with floats you'll easily get rounding errors on the order of those last few digits.